# How to distibute classes with PySpark and Jupyter

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, pickle, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have an annoying problem using jupyter notebook with spark.

I need to define a custom class inside the notebook and use it to perform some map operations

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark import SQLContext

conf = SparkConf().setMaster("spark://192.168.10.11:7077")\
              .setAppName("app_jupyter/")\
              .set("spark.cores.max", "10")

sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
distData = sc.parallelize(data)

class demo(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.test = value + 10
        pass

distData.map(lambda x : demo(x)).collect()
```

It gives the following error:

> PicklingError: Can't pickle : attribute lookup
>   **main**.demo failed

I know what this error is about, but I could't figure out a solution..

I have tried:

1. Define a demo.py python file outside the notebook. It works, but it is such a ugly solution ...
2. Create a dynamic module [like this](http://www.pythondoeswhat.com/2011/12/easily-import-dynamically-created.html), and then import it afterwards... This gives the same error

What would be a solution?...I want everything to work in the same notebook

It is possible to change something in:

1. The way spark works, maybe some pickle configuration
2. Something in the code...  Use some static magic approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reliable and elegant workaround here and this behavior is not particularly related to Spark. [This is all about fundamental design of the Python `pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#comparison-with-marshal)

> pickle can save and restore class instances transparently, however the **class definition must be importable** and **live in the same module as when the object was stored**.

Theoretically you could define a [custom cell magic](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/config/custommagics.html) which would:

- Write the content of a cell to a module.
- Import it.
- Call `SparkContext.addPyFile` to distribute the module.

```py
from IPython.core.magic import register_cell_magic
import importlib

@register_cell_magic
def spark_class(line, cell):
    module = line.strip()
    f = "{0}.py".format(module)

    with open(f, "w") as fw:
        fw.write(cell)

    globals()[module] = importlib.import_module(module)
    sc.addPyFile(f)
```

```py
In [2]: %%spark_class foo
   ...: class Foo(object):
   ...:     def __init__(self, x):
   ...:         self.x = x
   ...:     def __repr__(self):
   ...:         return "Foo({0})".format(self.x)
   ...: 

In [3]: sc.parallelize([1, 2, 3]).map(lambda x: foo.Foo(x)).collect()
Out[3]: [Foo(1), Foo(2), Foo(3)]
```

but it is a one time deal. Once file is marked for distribution it cannot be changed or redistributed. Moreover there is a problem of reloading imports on remote hosts. I can think of some more elaborate schemes but this is simply more trouble than it is worth.

Answer (score 0):

The answer [from zero323](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40941661/718174) is solid: there's no one "right" way to solve this problem.  You could indeed use Jupyter magic, as proposed.  One other way is to use Jupyter's `%%writefile` to have your code inline in a Jupyter cell but to then write it to disk as a python file.  Then you can both import the file to your Jupyter kernel session as well as ship it with your PySpark job (via `addPyFile()` as noted in the other answer).  Note that if you make changes to the code but don't restart your PySpark session, you'll have to get the updated code to PySpark somehow.

Can we make this easier? I wrote a [blogpost](https://pwais.github.io/oarph-oarphs/2020/02/03/atrick.html) about this topic as well as a PySpark Session wrapper ([`oarphpy.spark.NBSpark`](https://github.com/pwais/oarphpy/blob/da6b87cd1ed6b68189078c560ce13c6e290eb88f/oarphpy/spark.py#L715)) to help automate a lot of the tricky stuff.  See the Jupyter Notebook embedded in that post for a working example.  The overall pattern looks like this:

```
import os
import sys
CUSTOM_LIB_SRC_DIR = '/tmp/'
os.chdir(CUSTOM_LIB_SRC_DIR)

!mkdir -p mymodule
!touch mymodule/__init__.py
```

```
%%writefile mymodule/foo.py
class Zebra(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

```
sys.path.append(CUSTOM_LIB_SRC_DIR)
from mymodule.foo import Zebra

# Create Zebra() instances in the notebook
herd = [Zebra(name=str(i)) for i in range(10)]
```

```
# Now send those instances to PySpark!
from oarphpy.spark import NBSpark

NBSpark.SRC_ROOT = os.path.join(CUSTOM_LIB_SRC_DIR, 'mymodule')
spark = NBSpark.getOrCreate()
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(herd)
def get_name(z):
    return z.name
names = rdd.map(get_name).collect()
```

Additionally, if you make any changes to the `mymodule` files on disk (via `%%writefile` or otherwise), then `NBSpark` with automatically ship those changes to the active PySpark session.